# PHP SimpleXML use on complex XML to get data

Tags: php, simplexml

I try to get some data from some XML, which are very complex for me, so i ask you to help.

The XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <OAI-PMH xmlns="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/ http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/OAI-PMH.xsd">    <responseDate>2015-11-19T09:15:23Z</responseDate>    <request verb="GetRecord" identifier="oai:nava.hu:Document-2359008" metadataPrefix="navadoc">http://10.10.1.6/dev/navadoc/index.php</request> <GetRecord>
      <record>
         <header>
            <identifier>oai:nava.hu:Document-2359008</identifier>
            <datestamp>2015-11-19T08:51:52Z</datestamp>
         </header>
         <metadata>
            <navadoc:document xmlns:navadoc="http://nava.hu/oai-pmh/navadoc/xsd/" xmlns:document="http://nava.hu/oai-pmh/navadoc/xsd/document/" xsi:schemaLocation="http://nava.hu/oai-pmh/navadoc/xsd/ http://nava.hu/oai-pmh/navadoc/xsd/navadoc.xsd">
               <document:main>
                  <id>2359008</id>
                  <title>Summa</title>
                  <provider id="nava">NAVA</provider>
                  <collection id="101">Magyar Televízió 1</collection>
                  <type>document</type>
               </document:main>
               <document:meta>
                  <broadcast>
                     <date type="day">2015-11-06</date>
                     <date type="start_time">2015-11-06 14:17:19</date>
                     <date type="end_time">2015-11-06 14:39:07</date>
                     <date type="scheduled">2015-11-06 14:15:00</date>
                  </broadcast>
                  <duration>00:21:48</duration>
                  <genre type="NAVA">háttér- és közéleti műsor</genre>
                  <genre type="EBU">3.1.3 TÁRSADALMI/POLITIKAI MŰSOROK</genre>
                  <date type="production_year">2015</date>
                  <description type="guide">(nincs kh.) Közben: Tőzsdenyitás, Egy Perc Híradó Feliratozva a Teletext 111. oldalán. (26 perc) Summa, a Magyar Televízió új háttérműsora. Miért kellett magyar tulajdonba venni az étkezési jegy üzletet? Miért kell visszaszerezni a külföldi cégektől a közüzemi vállalatokat,és miért kell nekünk magyar járműgyártás? Miért kerültek egyáltalán korábban külföldi cégek kezébe ezek a komoly nyereséget termelő vállalatok? Mitől jobb gazda a magyar állam, mint a külföldi befektető? Kérdések, amelyekre a legilletékesebbek válaszolnak a Summában, szerdán, az Este című műsor után. Hírek és ami mögöttük van.</description>
                  <description type="provider" />
                  <description type="technote" />
                  <description type="subtitle" />
                  <description type="main" />
                  <description type="private">- projekt: full FELDOLGOZÁS VÁLTOZÁSA 2015-08-18 ADÁSNAPTÓL! 1-es projektfeladatban lesznek részletesebb adatokkal, daraboláskor csak sablon+MSZI ha van Törzsidő: M1, péntek, 14:15 feldolgozás:kulcsképek, tárgyszavak; (új stáblista kissé nehezen olvasható...) Spotokkal megszakítva, de egyelőre egybevágjuk</description>
                  <attributes>
                     <color>Színes</color>
                     <sound>Hangos</sound>
                     <screenformat>N/A</screenformat>
                  </attributes>
                  <agelimit>korhatár nélkül</agelimit>
                  <nava>
                     <document_level>1</document_level>
                     <processing_level>3</processing_level>
                     <processing_state>2</processing_state>
                     <access since="2015-11-09">FREE</access>
                     <validated>false</validated>
                     <collectable>true</collectable>
                     <hasvideo>true</hasvideo>
                     <hassubtitle>true</hassubtitle>
                     <preview>00:00:00</preview>
                  </nava>
                  <language iso="hun">magyar</language>
                  <title type="Főcím" id="751954">Summa</title>
                  <image image="allframe/2015/11/06/m1-87212/m1-87212-08221900.jpg" time="00:00:00" />
                  <image image="allframe/2015/11/06/m1-87212/m1-87212-08230000.jpg" time="00:00:41" />
                  <image image="allframe/2015/11/06/m1-87212/m1-87212-08240000.jpg" time="00:01:41" />
                  <image image="allframe/2015/11/06/m1-87212/m1-87212-08250000.jpg" time="00:02:41" />
                  <image image="allframe/2015/11/06/m1-87212/m1-87212-08260000.jpg" time="00:03:41" />
                  <image image="allframe/2015/11/06/m1-87212/m1-87212-08270000.jpg" time="00:04:41" />
                  <image image="allframe/2015/11/06/m1-87212/m1-87212-08280000.jpg" time="00:05:41" />
                  <image image="allframe/2015/11/06/m1-87212/m1-87212-08290000.jpg" time="00:06:41" />
                  <image image="allframe/2015/11/06/m1-87212/m1-87212-08300000.jpg" time="00:07:41" />
                  <image image="allframe/2015/11/06/m1-87212/m1-87212-08310000.jpg" time="00:08:41" />
                  <image image="allframe/2015/11/06/m1-87212/m1-87212-08320000.jpg" time="00:09:41" />
                  <image image="allframe/2015/11/06/m1-87212/m1-87212-08330000.jpg" time="00:10:41" />
                  <image image="allframe/2015/11/06/m1-87212/m1-87212-08340000.jpg" time="00:11:41" />
                  <image image="allframe/2015/11/06/m1-87212/m1-87212-08350000.jpg" time="00:12:41" />
                  <image image="allframe/2015/11/06/m1-87212/m1-87212-08360000.jpg" time="00:13:41" />
                  <image image="allframe/2015/11/06/m1-87212/m1-87212-08370000.jpg" time="00:14:41" />
                  <image image="allframe/2015/11/06/m1-87212/m1-87212-08380000.jpg" time="00:15:41" />
                  <image image="allframe/2015/11/06/m1-87212/m1-87212-08390000.jpg" time="00:16:41" />
                  <image image="allframe/2015/11/06/m1-87212/m1-87212-08400000.jpg" time="00:17:41" />
                  <image image="allframe/2015/11/06/m1-87212/m1-87212-08410000.jpg" time="00:18:41" />
                  <image image="allframe/2015/11/06/m1-87212/m1-87212-08420000.jpg" time="00:19:41" />
                  <image image="allframe/2015/11/06/m1-87212/m1-87212-08430000.jpg" time="00:20:41" />
                  <image image="allframe/2015/11/06/m1-87212/m1-87212-08440000.jpg" time="00:21:41" />
                  <image image="allframe/2015/11/06/m1-87212/m1-87212-08440700.jpg" time="00:21:48" />
                  <image type="LOGÓ" subtype="Műsorszámlogó" id="2964186" image="gallery/keyframe/2015/03/17/m1-76264/m1-76264-03302700.jpg">Summa</image>
                  <image type="SZEMÉLY / CSOPORT" subtype="Személy / Személyek" time="00:01:28" id="3180774" image="gallery/keyframe/2015/11/06/m1-87212/m1-87212-08234700.jpg">Rogán Antal, miniszter, Miniszterelnöki Kabinet Iroda</image>
                  <image type="SZEMÉLY / CSOPORT" subtype="Személy / Személyek" time="00:02:33" id="3180778" image="gallery/keyframe/2015/11/06/m1-87212/m1-87212-08245200.jpg">György László phd, közgazdász</image>
                  <image type="SZEMÉLY / CSOPORT" subtype="Személy / Személyek" time="00:03:03" id="3180782" image="gallery/keyframe/2015/11/06/m1-87212/m1-87212-08252200.jpg">Horváth Dániel, vezető kutató, Migrációkutató Intézet</image>
                  <image type="SZEMÉLY / CSOPORT" subtype="Személy / Személyek" time="00:03:45" id="3180788" image="gallery/keyframe/2015/11/06/m1-87212/m1-87212-08260400.jpg">Lattmann Tamás, nemzetközi jogász</image>
                  <image type="INFORMÁCIÓS TARTALOM" subtype="Téma / Felirat / Inzert" time="00:07:15" id="3180790" image="gallery/keyframe/2015/11/06/m1-87212/m1-87212-08293400.jpg">Amerikai-magyar kereskedelmi kapcsolatok, 1989 óta</image>
                  <image type="SZEMÉLY / CSOPORT" subtype="Személy / Személyek" time="00:07:28" id="3180796" image="gallery/keyframe/2015/11/06/m1-87212/m1-87212-08294700.jpg">Kerekes György, igazgató, Nemzetközi tanácsadás, Századvég Zrt.</image>
                  <image type="SZEMÉLY / CSOPORT" subtype="Személy / Személyek" time="00:08:53" id="3180848" image="gallery/keyframe/2015/11/06/m1-87212/m1-87212-08311200.jpg">Colleen Bell, az USA magyarországi nagykövete</image>
                  <image type="SZEMÉLY / CSOPORT" subtype="Személy / Személyek" time="00:12:13" id="3180856" image="gallery/keyframe/2015/11/06/m1-87212/m1-87212-08343200.jpg">Mészáros László, elnök, Országos Magyar Méhészeti Egyesület</image>
                  <image type="SZEMÉLY / CSOPORT" subtype="Személy / Személyek" time="00:12:59" id="3180858" image="gallery/keyframe/2015/11/06/m1-87212/m1-87212-08351800.jpg">Kutasi Tamás, méhészmester</image>
                  <image type="SZEMÉLY / CSOPORT" subtype="Személy / Személyek" time="00:14:05" id="3180862" image="gallery/keyframe/2015/11/06/m1-87212/m1-87212-08362400.jpg">Petneházy Antal, méhész</image>
                  <image type="SZEMÉLY / CSOPORT" subtype="Személy / Személyek" time="00:14:50" id="3180864" image="gallery/keyframe/2015/11/06/m1-87212/m1-87212-08370900.jpg">Jandácsik Attila, Pest Megyei Méhészeti Szaktanácsadó</image>
                  <relation type="tartalmazza">2358946</relation>
                  <media format="REAL" bitrate="128" resolution="192x144" clipBegin="08:22:19" clipEnd="08:44:07" media="2015/11/06/m1-20151106-055500.rm" />
                  <media format="REAL" bitrate="512" resolution="384x288" clipBegin="01:16:06" clipEnd="01:37:54" media="2015/11/06/m1-20151106-055500-07061300-12035300.rm" />
                  <media format="MPG" bitrate="8000" resolution="704x576" clipBegin="01:16:06" clipEnd="01:37:54" media="2015/11/06/m1-87212-07061300-12035300.mpg" />
                  <media format="MP4" bitrate="768" resolution="352x288" clipBegin="01:16:06" clipEnd="01:37:54" media="Broadcast/2015/11/06/m1-20151106-055500-07061300-12035300.mp4" />
                  <track type="subtitle" format="srt" language="hun" file="2015/11/06/m1-20151106-055500-07061300-12035300.srt" />
                  <person type="contributor" id="103356" role="hírigazgató" sex="Férfi" comment="szerkesztőségvezető, MTV">Németh Zsolt</person>
                  <person type="contributor" id="133458" role="produkciós vezető" sex="Férfi" comment="produkciós vezető">Tóth István</person>
                  <person type="contributor" id="148662" role="kreatív producer" sex="Férfi" comment="kreatív producer">Pető Zoltán</person>
                  <subject source="Földrajzi név" id="30">Európai Unió</subject>
                  <subject source="Földrajzi név" id="1403">Egyesült Államok</subject>
                  <subject source="Tezaurusz" id="4905">méhészet</subject>
                  <subject source="Tezaurusz" id="4906">méz</subject>
                  <subject source="Tezaurusz" id="4942">bevándorlás</subject>
                  <subject source="Tezaurusz" id="8945">migráció</subject>
                  <subject source="Tezaurusz" id="11161">menekült</subject>
                  <workflow date="2015-11-09" time="07:48:03" user="265" name="mate">Létrehozás</workflow>
                  <workflow date="2015-11-16" time="10:17:52" user="488" name="vera">Feladat kiosztása</workflow>
                  <workflow date="2015-11-19" time="08:51:52" user="488" name="vera">Feldolgozás vége</workflow>
               </document:meta>
            </navadoc:document>
         </metadata>
      </record>    </GetRecord> </OAI-PMH>
```

I want to get all record from
 where type="SZEMÉLY / CSOPORT"

I dont know if the php simplexml is enougth for this, or i have to use some other object.

Comment: Hi! This is not a code writing service, so you need to be a bit more specific with your question, and show what you've written or researched so far, and where exactly you're stuck. There are quite good examples of SimpleXML in the PHP manual, or elsewhere online, so I suggest reading those and getting an idea of how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can use `simplexml_load_file` and then use `xpath`.
For example, lets assume your xml is in 'temp.xml'.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("temp.xml");
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('e', 'http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/');
```

This will find your 10 images from the xml:

```
$images = $xml->xpath('//e:image[@type="SZEMÉLY / CSOPORT"]');
```

Now you can loop the $images, and each $image is of type `SimpleXMLElement`.
Then you can get the value and the values of the properties for example:

```
foreach ($images as $image) {
    $content =  $image->__toString();
    $type =  $image->attributes()->type;
    $subtype =  $image->attributes()->subtype;
    $time = $image->attributes()->time;
    $attributes = $image->attributes()->id;
    $image =  $image->attributes()->image;
}
```